# Asp.net Where i use Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use `Html.BeginForm()` in some Asp.net M but i did not understand where its use becomes compulsory .Why i really needed to use it in my Views..? It may be a silly question but i am perplexed and confused to use this Html-helper in mvc...??

Here below i have code for search option but i did not know what is meaning of `FormMethod.Get` so please explain it briefly  ?

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get))
{ 
    <b>Search Option</b>

    @Html.TextBox("Search") <input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
}
```

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Its never 'compulsory', but it ensures the html is correctly generated and is  generally less code than writing it manually, so why not use it.

Comment: Ali can you give me an example if i did not use it then what will be the result??

Comment: When you need <form>..</form> use this html helper, it will write same html tag to the response. Razor syntax for <form> tags. FormMethod decide Get/Post will be used to submit the data.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.BeginForm` is a helper method which generates the HTML markup for a `form` tag to the page/view. When you use it will `using` , it properly creates a end form tag (`<\form>`) as well. So basically when razor executes the code in your question, it will generate markup like this

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="get">
 <!-- markup generated by other elements inside the form will goes here -->
</form>
```

One benefit of using the helper method is , it properly generates the correct markup that you /i write the markup of form tag and the attributes needed which is prone to human errors (typo). Also the helper method always generate the correct relative path to the action method for the value of the `action` attribute.

It is **not necessary** to use this method for your view. If you prefer to write clean-readable UI code, you would do that by replacing your helper method calls with something like

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="get">
    <b>Search Option</b>
    <input id="Search" name="Search" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

In ASP.NET Core, we have tag helpers which allows us to write code to generate form(or other form elements) as close to the above hand written html markup. So the code will basically look more like pure HTML than C# or VB.NET